# Zip Python Array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a big array:

```
[['I love these vitamins so far', 'and my doctor recommended the 5000IU 
dosage', 'Love the product!  Power Vitamin with my Power Drink!', 'Great 
Product - Works Great!', 'Love all that goes into this vitamin D!', 'great 
product', 'Best Vitamin D3', 'Great product! You will not be disappointed.', 
'Doctor prescribed', 'Made in the USA'], ['MusicLova', 'Mg', 'Rosie', 'Stacey 
Chillemi "Author Stacey Chillemi"', 'Denise', 'jim easley', 'Betterlife', 
'Martin A. Leddy', 'Angela Wright', 'Bob Jama'], 
['http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/A3HJLBNJMSQBQ5', etc .. 
reviews/R2AQ19W7L9D2SP', 'www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R28OFZC87A7XIM', 
'www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R33AMKSHD88B0Q'], 1, 'NatureWise']
```

I have 2 elements at the end I want applied to every array.  I want to create an array of arrays with the inner array just being one element from each list?  I think using zip is the easiest way but I get too many item to unpack?

```
zip(data)
```

For example, I want:

```
   [["I love these vitamins so far", "MusicLova", 
   'http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/A3HJLBNJMSQBQ5', 1, "NatureWise"] ..        
    etc ]
```

and all of the lists have the same # of elements, beside the last 2 elements not within arrays

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: @BillyJoe instead of including "etc" in your example, provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do it:

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c'],'me','you']
>>> [list(i)+x[-2:] for i in zip(*x[:-2])]

>>> [[1, 'a', 'me', 'you'], [2, 'b', 'me', 'you'], [3, 'c', 'me', 'you']]
```

Comment: wow, wow ... won't you ask me on a date first?

Answer (score 1):

`zip()` will work if the input is prepared appropriately, e.g.:

```
x = [['I love these vitamins so far', 'and my doctor recommended the 5000IU dosage', 
'Love the product!  Power Vitamin with my Power Drink!', 
'Great Product - Works Great!'], ['MusicLova', 'Mg', 'Rosie', 'Stacey Chillemi'], 
['www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/A3HJLBNJMSQBQ5', 
'www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2AQ19W7L9D2SP', 
'www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R28OFZC87A7XIM', 
'www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R33AMKSHD88B0Q'], 1, 'NatureWise']

x[-1] = [x[-1]]*len(x[0])
x[-2] = [x[-2]]*len(x[0])

print(list(zip(*x)))
```

... from which the output is:

`[('I love these vitamins so far', 'MusicLova', 'www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/A3HJLBNJMSQBQ5', 
1, 'NatureWise'), ('and my doctor recommended the 5000IU dosage', 'Mg', 'www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2AQ19W7L9D2SP', 1, 'NatureWise'), ('Love the product!  Power Vitamin with my Power Drink!', 'Rosie', 'www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R28OFZC87A7XIM', 1, 'NatureWise'), ('Great Product - Works Great!', 'Stacey Chillemi', 'www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R33AMKSHD88B0Q', 1, 'NatureWise')]`

Comment: yeah, it's silly to have the input be as OP has it.  and it's so easy to adjust.